# Sending ListBlog response in unary streaming

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I am trying to return list of items from grpc without streaimg API and not finding any solution or example , I know we use this kind of  `proto file`  when using streaming

```
message ListBlogResponse {
    Blog blog = 1;
}
```

and then `Blog`

```
message Blog {
    string id = 1;
    string author_id = 2;
    string title = 3;
    string content = 4;
}
```

but I want to send response once without using any streaming some thing like this :

```
return &api.ListBlogResponse{
        Blog: items,
    }, nil
```

what will be the protofile for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a message containing multiple blogs:

```
message BlogEntries {
   repeated Blog blog = 1;
}
```

Then you can return:

```
return &BlogEntries{Blog:entries},nil
```